# Does CsvHelper support multiple Prefix?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

Hi I'm using "CsvHelper" (v 2.16.3), I want to use prefix in my object **that will append the child prefix to the parent prefix.**

But I didn't manged to do so,
Does CsvJelper support that?

**For example:
My Model:**

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public ExampleModelNode leftNode { get; set; }
    public ExampleModelNode rightNode { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleModelNode
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public NodeData data { get; set; }
}
public class NodeData
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

**My mapping class:**

```
    class ExampleModelMap : CsvClassMap<ExampleModel>
    {
        public ExampleModelMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.status);
            References<ExampleModelNodeMap>(m => m.leftNode).Prefix("Right_");
            References<ExampleModelNodeMap>(m => m.rightNode).Prefix("Left_");
        }
    }
    class ExampleModelNodeMap : CsvClassMap<ExampleModelNode>
    {
        public ExampleModelNodeMap()
        {
            AutoMap(false,true);
            References<NodeDataMap>(m => m.data).Prefix("Data_");
        }
    }
    class NodeDataMap : CsvClassMap<NodeData>
    {
        public NodeDataMap()
        {
            AutoMap(false,true);
        }
    }
```

**Init and running:**

```
        ExampleModel exampleModel = new ExampleModel()
        {
            status = "A",
            rightNode = new ExampleModelNode()
            {
                status = "L",
                data = new NodeData()
                {
                    data = "L Data"
                }
            },
            leftNode = new ExampleModelNode()
            {
                status = "R",
                data = new NodeData()
                {
                    data = "R Data"
                }
            }
        };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new ExampleModelMap());
        csv.Configuration.PrefixReferenceHeaders = true;
        csv.WriteHeader(typeof(ExampleModel));
        csv.WriteRecord(exampleModel);

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        File.WriteAllText("csv.csv", sb.ToString());
```

**The output is:**

[image]

**But the expected output that I want is:**

[image]

Does CsvHelper support that? How can I get this mapping?

Comment: can you provide link for this library?

Comment: Sure, https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/